Finding a binomial sum with the help of the series $(x+1)^{\pm 1/2}$
I have to find the following sum:
$$\binom{2k-2}{k-1}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2k-4}{k-2}+\frac{1}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2k-6}{k-3}+ \ ...\ + \frac{1}{k-1}\binom{2k-4}{k-2}\binom{2}{1}+\frac{1}{k}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}$$
Here is what I provided by myself. I see a way of calculating it in using the following series:
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\cdot \binom{2k-2}{k-1}\cdot\frac{x^k}{4^{k-1}}$$
EDITED:
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k}\cdot \binom{2k-2}{k-1}\cdot\frac{x^k}{4^{k-1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\cdot \binom{2k}{k}\cdot x^k$$
To make the terms closer to the original expression we can substitute 4 instead of $x$ and divide the first series by 4:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+4}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} = 1+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\cdot \binom{2k-2}{k-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} = \sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\binom{2k}{k}$$
EDITED: It's nonsense, we should substitute $-4t$, not $4$. 
Now I'm stuck and don't know how to transform these series into the expression above. Please give me a hint.

Two issues with your attempt:

The step where you set $x$ to $4$ is [at least in the classical sense] nonsense.  You ended up with divergent series equaling a number.
The series you started with for $\sqrt{1+x}$ has a typo/error.

Instead, since we'd still like to get rid of both the powers of $4$ and the powers of $-1$, let's set $x=-4t$:
$$\sqrt{1-4t} = 1 - 2\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac1k\binom{2k-2}{k-1}t^k \\ \frac1{\sqrt{1-4t}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}k t^k$$
Now multiply both sides:
$$1= \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}k t^k - 2\sum_{k\geq 1} A_k t^k$$
where $A_k$ is the expression you need to find.  Comparing coefficients gives $$A_k = \frac12\binom{2k}k$$

Thank you! I edited the post.
